# TabLayoutMediator for viewpager2 is not available on the new android studio version4.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

`TabLayoutMediator` for `ViewPager2` is not available on the new android studio version4.0.0, Please is there any alternative to that

Comment: Post your dependencies in build.gradle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class [`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator) is included in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and it **requires** at least the version `1.1.0`.

Add in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    //....
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks myou friend, your solution worked like charm. I changed the version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 and it worked. Thanks again

Comment: how did you first know that it is included it version as minimum as 1.1.0